# I have some spacing error in my pascals triangle using C programming

Tags: c

The spacing is off in my code, can anyone help. I have attempted it (shown below)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int factorial(int n){
    int fact = 1;

    if(n == 0){
        return 1;
    } else {
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            fact = fact * i;
        }
        return fact;
    }
}

int choose(int n, int r)
{
    int ans;

    ans = (factorial(n))/((factorial(r))*(factorial(n-r)));
    return ans;
}

void triangle(int numOfRows){
    for(int n=0; n<numOfRows; n++)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=numOfRows-n; i++){
            printf("   ");    // Note the extra space
        }
        for(int r=0; r<=n; r++)
        {
           printf("%5d ",choose(n,r)); // Changed to %3d
        }    
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    int rows;
    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);

    while(rows > 0 && rows <=13){

        triangle(rows);

        printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
        scanf("%d", &rows);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output should be: 
[image]
Thanks i'd appreciate it (this is also my first time using this site, so sorry for bad format stuff).

The program needs to work up to 13 rows (which is shown in my while loop in my main functions).

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text output; embed the text in the question.

Comment: Factorial 13 is too big to fit into a 32-bit integer (signed or unsigned); you get overflow.  (`n = 12, log2(n!) = 28.83545523407540696694, n! = 479001600`
—— `n = 13, log2(n!) = 32.53589495221649912738, n! = 6227020800`)  You also need fairly large numbers by the time you reach row 13; you need to worry about numbers with 3 digits (but the factorials are much bigger).

Comment: When I change the computation type from `int` to `long` (on a 64-bit machine other than Windows 64-bit — `long long` would work on a 32-bit machine or Windows 64-bit, and on non-Windows 64-bit machines too), your code works OK up to 13, within limits. The primary concern might be that the numbers are right justified rather than centred in the field.  But you need to show what you expect (and get) for rows 6 and 12 (rows with 2-digit and 3-digit coefficients).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a couple of changes to have the triangle aligned to the left as in the expected output.

First, you are adding 3 extra spaces in the first loop with the `printf("   ")`, that is fixed using `<` instead of `<=` in the loop condition.

Second, there are 4 extra chars added due to the `"%5d "` in the second `printf` call, you need to avoid that for the first iteration (when `r == 0`) using just `"%d "`.

Here's how the `triangle()` function will look like after the changes:

```
void triangle(int numOfRows) {
    for(int n = 0; n < numOfRows; n++) {
        for(int i = 1; i < numOfRows-n; i++) {
            printf("   ");
        }
        for(int r = 0; r <= n; r++) {
           printf(r == 0 ? "%d " : "%5d ", choose(n, r));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

And some example output (works up to 13 without a problem, at least on my 64-bit Linux with both gcc and clang):

```
Enter the number of rows: 3
      1 
   1     1 
1     2     1 
Enter the number of rows: 4
         1 
      1     1 
   1     2     1 
1     3     3     1 

Enter the number of rows: 5
            1 
         1     1 
      1     2     1 
   1     3     3     1 
1     4     6     4     1 
Enter the number of rows: 13
                                    1 
                                 1     1 
                              1     2     1 
                           1     3     3     1 
                        1     4     6     4     1 
                     1     5    10    10     5     1 
                  1     6    15    20    15     6     1 
               1     7    21    35    35    21     7     1 
            1     8    28    56    70    56    28     8     1 
         1     9    36    84   126   126    84    36     9     1 
      1    10    45   120   210   252   210   120    45    10     1 
   1    11    55   165   330   462   462   330   165    55    11     1 
1    12    66   220   495   792   924   792   495   220    66    12     1
```